# How to caulk wide gap around bath

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, caulking, silicone

I want to re-do the caulk around my bath, but the gap starts small and grows to about 4cm. It doesn't need to be a perfect finish -- just enough to stop the water until the bathroom is refurbished properly.

Do I just apply silicone caulk as normal or should I use something to bridge the gap?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Duct tape seems apt.

Comment: Clean all that old gunk out. Then  use a pvc trim molding to cover the gap.

Comment: Silicon is a hard, flaky mineral. It's not a building material.

Comment: Something like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TledktNTMU) show

Comment: That's it! Thanks, @Kris. I'll try copy what the guy in the video did.

Comment: @Kris post your video as an answer, and include some details (so it's not link only) so it can be accepted. Much more useful than an "answer in comments".